# How to pronounce ICAO?

Tags: icao

How to pronounce ICAO, correctly?
Civil Aviation students claim that their teacher told them to pronounce it as

> /ˌaɪˌkeɪˈoʊ/, eye-KAY-oh

but when I look at Cambridge Dictionary it pronounces ICAO differently: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/icao

So, how do you pronounce it correctly in Aviation?

Comment: This question is mine :) I couldn't delete it. I thought that SE network will automatically join the accounts when I write there my email, but it didn't :)

Comment: @garakchy See https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: It seems you are presuming, that the Civil Aviation Instructors are teaching the pronunciation the wrong way?

Answer (score 3):

This is 2 years after the primary conversation, but just in case anyone searches this, here's an explanation. The difference between these two schools of thought are that one is an acronym and one is an initialism. "ICAO" is pronounced as an acronym, meaning that one pronounces it as a word, rather than as the letters themselves. In the same way, "NASA" is an acronym because it's pronounced as a word.
Conversely, FBI or CIA are initialisms and are spoken by their initials.
Literary devices can be both fun and deceiving at times. I hope this clears things up for the next person.

Answer (score 2):

I have usually seen people in the industry pronounce it as eye-kay-oh. Technically, the correct way would be to pronounce the letters individually as per the English language which is why the dictionary has that but I have never seen anyone pronounce it that way.

Comment: "Technically, the correct way would be to pronounce the letters individually" – Do you have a source for that? I don't think anyone would say that technically, the correct pronunciation of NASA is "en-a-es-a."

Comment: It's an abbreviation and not an actual word, so pronouncing it as a word doesn't really have a correct way... but saying the individual letters of the abbreviation should be correct. Just like the NYPD is not called "nyeped" or the CIA is not called "chia" or something.

Comment: @Jan It often depends on how _pronounceable_ an abbreviation is. "NASA", "ICAO" and "IATA" work pretty well, "FBI" and "NYPD" don't. Sometimes people get creative: the computer database language "SQL" (structured query language) is often pronounced "sequel".

Comment: ICAO pronounces it eye-kay-oh [on their own YouTube channel](https://youtu.be/K-fU4GRyuIg?t=21) in English, so I wouldn't say that the organization's own pronunciation is technically incorrect. I don't know how that applies to all countries or languages though; ICAO has other official acronyms for other languages like OACI in French and Spanish plus Cyrillic (apparently a transliteration of ICAO rather than a translation), Arabic (also a transliteration), and Chinese, as shown in [ICAO Emblem and its History](https://www.icao.int/ICAO%20History/icao_emblem_history.pdf).

Comment: @PerlDuck that'd depend on which database engine you're using. Oracle users traditionally say Sequel, DB/2 users S Q L, for example.

Comment: @PerlDuck: Or "squill".

Comment: @Vikki that's one I've never heard...

Answer (score 0):

American aviators reference it as Eye-Kay-Oh.  If you speak in English to folks in the Aviation industry, they will immediately understand Eye-Kay-Oh.  On the contrary, if you said "Eye - See - Eh - Oh", you will probably get a quizzical expression.

If you are working in a French (or alternative) language environment, then perhaps they may reference the organization differently.

Stick with your aviation instructors - they know what they are doing.

Comment: I've never heard it stated anything other than in full correct spelling out of every single letter.

Comment: Are you an American Aviator?  What is your background? Just trying to understand in the context of the question.

Comment: I'm an American (although not an aviator), and _I've_ always heard it pronounced "EYE-cow".

Comment: In the FAA I've always heard it pronounced eye-kay-oh.